# crontab: "Temporary crontab no longer owned by you."

Tags: cron

I reverted from Linuxmint 18 Cinnamon 64bit to Linuxmint 17.3 Cinnamon 64bit and can no longer create a cron job. I have separate root (/) and home (/home/my-user-name) partitions and left the home partition untouched when I did the 17.3 installation.

I was having all sorts of difficulties creating a cron job, so I installed gnome-scheduler and tried to create a cron job that way. I got a warning dialog box titled

> "Warning: Working directory of executed tasks"

and the message content is

> "Note about working directory of executed tasks: Recurrent tasks will
>   be run from the home directory."

I clicked OK and the job shows up in the terminal as follows:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /home/my-user-name/wallpaper_changer.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_4
```

My wallpaper does not change every minute as it should. The script runs just fine from the command line and produces no output. Permissions are 744 octal for the script. This all worked fine under Mint 18, but I had the script run just once a day. I set it to run every minute only for testing purposes.

If I try the normal cron job editing method, I get

```
$ crontab -e
Temporary crontab no longer owned by you.
Error while editing crontab
```

Then I get an empty nano buffer rather than the normal crontab template full of commented lines. When I try to write my nano buffer to file /tmp/crontab.lmuwIe/crontab I get this error message:

> [ Error writing /tmp/lmuwIe/crontab: Permission denied ]

Finally,

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root crontab 35984 Feb  9  2013 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Will I ever be able to create a cron job again?

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab      4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root         4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 root my-user-name  188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name
```

---

@Gilles
Well I've made a lot of progress. I got rid of all the error weirdness by reinstalling cron. Now everything works just as it should when I use

```
$ crontab -e
```

**except** that the script I've been using for years doesn't run.

But another script does run; so I'm lost.

Here's what I've got right now:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/my-user-name/wallpaper_changer.sh
* * * * * date >> /home/my-user-name/crontest.txt
```

(I didn't include the 20-odd lines of comments that precede the cron jobs.)

The date job runs exactly as it should but the wallpaper_changer.sh job doesn't do anything. I've used this for years and now it doesn't work.  The script works fine from the command line and used to work fine from cron.

```
$ ls -l /home/my-user-name/wallpaper_changer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my-user-name my-user-name 694 Jun  2 14:30 /home/my-user-name/wallpaper_changer.sh

$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

What's up with this?

Comment: it sounds to me like something is scanning /tmp and resetting permissions or ownerships

Comment: Downgrading is not officially supported. Something specific to Mint 18 must have crept into a configuration file somewhere. This is possibly related to the location of temporary files. Post the output of `echo "TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"; ls -ld /tmp "$TMPDIR" "$(mktemp -d)"`

Comment: @Gilles:

echo "TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"; ls -ld /tmp "$TMPDIR" "$(mktemp -d)"

TMPDIR=

ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

drwxrwxrwt 15 root  root  4096 Sep 24 11:27 /tmp

drwx------  2 my-user-name my-user-name 4096 Sep 24 11:27 /tmp/tmp.6QGdOkrYg4

Comment: Everything looks normal with temporary files in general so I guess the problem is with cron. Does `crontab -e` work (editing root's crontab, which is neither your crontab nor the system crontab)? What's the output of `sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs` ?

Comment: @Gilles:

$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs

total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab   4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 root my-user-name  188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name

Comment: @Gilles:
`$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab   4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root              4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 root my-user-name        188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name`

BTW, thanks for helping me!

When I use crontab -e, nano opens but without the crontab template file that has several commented lines. the title bar of the terminal window reads:

`File: /tmp/crontab.ZK0sDB/crontab`
Is having the octal permissions on the file /var/spool/cron/crontabs/my-user-name set to 600 right?

Comment: when I hit <ENTER> I get [ Error writing /tmp/crontab.ZK0sDB/crontab: Permission denied ]

When I hit ^X to exit, I get

Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?

If I hit Y for yes, I go back to

File Name to Write: /tmp/crontab.ZK0sDB/crontab

so this is a sort of infinite loop.

If I hit N for no, I leave nano and there is no job listed when I type

$ crontab -l

Comment: @DonNadie Fix the permissions in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` before you run the `crontab` commands. By the way, to add information, please edit your question (use the “edit” button), comments are short and have little formatting by design.

Comment: Please **edit your question** (not my answer) to add more information.

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit permissions on the crontab binary and set them back to what they are when you do a fresh install.

#### NOT WORKING permissions:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root crontab 40264 Oct  7  2017 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Action, do as root or using sudo:

```
chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab
chmod u-s /usr/bin/crontab
```

#### WORKING permissions:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 40264 Oct  7  2017 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Taken from a fresh working installation, the working permissions are set during installation.

No idea why they changed later on.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed. I had the group set to "root" on crontab.

Comment: Perfect.  This is VERY hard to track down - and hard to google for, too!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs
> total 12
> drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab      4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
> drwxr-xr-x 5 root root         4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
> -rw------- 1 root my-user-name  188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name
> ```

The ownership of `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/my-user-name` is wrong. You should be the owner. That would explain why cron can't overwrite the file. Also the file would normally be in `crontab` group but I don't think it matters.

You can fix this by running

```
sudo chown my-user-name /var/spool/cron/crontabs/my-user-name
```

I don't know what could have caused this and I don't see how it could be related to a system downgrade. The underlying issues might cause other problems.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the problem remains as before. First I tried `sudo chown my-user-name /var/spool/cron/crontabs/my-user-name` so that `$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root  crontab 4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root    4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 my-user-name my-user-name    188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name
` and got `$ crontab -e
Temporary crontab no longer owned by you.
Error while editing crontab`

Comment: Then I tried `$ sudo chgrp crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/my-user-name` so that `$ sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root  crontab 4096 Sep 25 03:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root    4096 Sep 23 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 my-user-name crontab  188 Sep 25 03:23 my-user-name` and got  `$  crontab -e
Temporary crontab no longer owned by you.
Error while editing crontab` again. When nano starts, there's no crontab template with a bunch of commented lines. Everything goes south just as in my previous comments.

Comment: @DonNadie Hmmm. I don't know. Please test whether `crontab -e` works as root, and create a new test user and test whether `crontab -e` works as that user.

Comment: @DonNadie Edit **your question**, not my answer.